# Text inside TextFormField isn't aligned to center - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I saw some resolutions using Padding, but I don't know if that is the best solution... Is there another way to center the text inside a TextFormField?

[formField-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzyP1.png)

```
class _InputFormFieldState extends State<InputFormField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      width: this.widget.width,
      height: 50,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
        boxShadow: ThemeEffect.shadowInputField()
      ),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: this.widget.controller,
        validator: this.widget.validator,     
        style: ThemeText.sign_up_input_field,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          errorBorder:OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: ThemeColor.flamingo,
              width: 2
            ),
          ),
          errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
          hintText: this.widget.hintText,
          hintStyle:  ThemeText.sign_up_input_field_hint,
          border: new OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
          ),
          filled: true,
          fillColor: ThemeColor.white
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
TextField(
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `TextFormField`.

Add - `textAlign: TextAlign.center,`

```
...
child: TextFormField(
            controller: this.widget.controller,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,   // Add this Line
            validator: this.widget.validator,
            style: ThemeText.sign_up_input_field,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use padding since this property is already provided by the widget, so you just need to add TextAlign.center to fix this, like so:

```
TextFormField(
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
```